# Como saber si un texto es tautograma ( definicion dentro )

Tags: java, array, string, poo

Tengo un ejercicio a resolver: Saber si un texto es tautograma ( es si todas las palabras del texto empiezan por la misma letra).

Estoy haciéndolo en POO. Tengo los (suficientes) objetos creados, junto a una clase que me lee el archivo ".txt" .

Clase Palabra:

```
public class Paraula {

    private char[] Paraula;

    public Paraula(char[] Paraula) {
        this.Paraula = Paraula;
    }

    public char[] getParaula() {
        return Paraula;
    }

    public void setParaula(char[] Paraula) {
        this.Paraula = Paraula;
    }   
}
```

Clase que me lee el fichero:

```
public class llegirFitxer {
    FileReader fr; 
    BufferedReader br; 

    public  llegirFitxer() {
        try {
            fr = new FileReader("text.txt");
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(llegirFitxer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }       
    }

    public String llegirLinia() throws IOException{
        return br.readLine();
    }  
}
```

Y este es mi main:

```
public class PreExamen1 {

    LT lt = new LT();
    Paraula p;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PreExamen1 pe = new PreExamen1();
        pe.guardarText();
    }

    public void guardarText() throws IOException {
        Paraula[] Paraules = new Paraula[5];
        llegirFitxer textLlegit = new llegirFitxer();
        System.out.println(textLlegit);
        for (int i = 0; i < Paraules.length; i++) {
            Paraules[i] = new Paraula(textLlegit.llegirLinia()); //Llegir l'String de paraules
        }
//        
//        p = new Paraula(Paraules);
    }
}
```

Aqui lo que contiene el archivo txt:

```
paraulap

perop

picop

perop

pedp
```

Lo he escrito yo para que se pueda verificar el tautograma.

El problema erradica en que quiero meter las palabras dentro de mi `Array`. No se si hacer un `String` para que me lea cada linea, o como llenar la `Array`. Estoy atascadíssimo aqui.

PD: La clase LT es simplemente para leer de teclado y no utilizar el `Scanner`. De todos modos se puede utilizar el `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si debes hacerlo con esas clases obligatoriamente. Si no es así yo haría un método en tu clase LeerFichero que leyera todo el contenido del archivo de texto y fuera comprobando línea a línea las condiciones que te pide.

Te pongo un ejemplo que no sé si servirá:

```
public boolean esTautograma() throws IOException {

    // Usaremos este String para guardar la línea que leemos
    String linea;

    // Será nuestro punto de control.
    // Si todas las primeras letras son iguales
    // todas tienen que ser iguales a ésta
    char primeraLetra = 0;

    // Tenemos que averiguar si se trata de la primera palabra
    boolean primeraVez = true;

    // Hay que retornar un resultado del proceso
    // Será true si se trata de un tautograma y false en caso contrario
    boolean resultado = true;

    // Recorremos el texto, pero antes preguntamos si se puede leer del archivo
    while (br.ready()) {

        // Tomamos la primera línea
        linea = br.readLine();

        // Comprobamos que no se trata de una cadena de texto sin longitud
        // Si no tiene longitud no nos vale, así que sólo entrará si tiene 
        // por lo menos un carácter imprimible
        if (linea.length() != 0) {

            // Si es el primer ciclo del bucle entramos aquí
            if (primeraVez) {

                // Cambiamos el valor de primeraVez para que en los 
                // siguientes ciclos no vuelva a entrar
                primeraVez = false;

                // Tomamos el punto de control, es decir, 
                // la primera letra de la primera palabra
                primeraLetra = linea.charAt(0);
            } else {

                // Como primeraVez ya no es true, entramos aquí en los 
                // siguientes ciclos

                // Comprobamos que la primera letra de la siguiente palabra
                // sea igual a nuestro punto de control
                // Si es distinto entramos
                if (linea.charAt(0) != primeraLetra) {

                    // Como la letra que estamos comparando es distinta de 
                    // nuestro punto de control ponemos el resultado a false
                    resultado = false;

                    // Ya no tenemos necesidad de seguir recorriendo el texto
                    // Salimos del bucle
                    break;
                } // Si no entramos nunca aquí será un tautograma
            }
        }
    }

    // Retornamos el valor del resultado
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Me ha ido genial. Para hacerlo con POO solo he tenido que cambiar dos cosas. Es que mi problema principal es pensar bien en cómo ejecutar el texto. Luego todo lo demás sale solo. Muchas gracias por todo!